# groovy to remove json unwated array label

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

I have this json and I want to remove the field item.

```
{ "field": "AAA", "list": { "item": [ { "field01": "111", "field02": "222" }, { "field01": "333", "field02": "444" } ] }}
```

I'm using this json slurper groovy but it's returnung null.

```
def myJson = '..' //above json; def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper(); def jsonObject=jsonParser.parseText(myJson); return JsonOutput.toJson(jsonObject["item"])
```

The expected output is:

```
{ "field": "AAA", "list": [ { "field01": "111", "field02": "222" }, { "field01": "333", "field02": "444" } ]}
```

How can I do to remove the field "item"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def myJson = '..' //above json; 
def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper(); 
def jsonObject=jsonParser.parseText(myJson); 
jsonObject.list=jsonObject.list.item
return JsonOutput.toJson(jsonObject)
```